# SharePoint designer 2013 stops working when one front end server is down

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, failover

I have a sharepoint farm with 2 WFEs and a 2 SQL mirorred servers
I have set up a workflow manager farm on the 2 WFEs to make sure all workflows keep running if one WFE is down, but when one WFE is down 2013 workflows do not run at all - what am I missing?

This is the server that is down showing that the workflow farm is stopped:

[image]

How can I make the workflow manager keep running even if one of the servers is down?

Getting this now:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51716.sharepoint-20132016-troubleshooting-workflow-farm.aspx):

- open SharePoint PowerShell
- `get-wfFarm`
- `get-wfFarmStatus`
- `get-sbFarm`
- `get-sbFarmStatus`

check these services if they're running:

1. Workflow Manager Backend
2. Service Bus Message Broker
3. Service Bus Gateway
4. Windows Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)

Hope it helps.

Comment: already came across it and it didn't help me. Trying to follow this now but still getting stuck: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2014/05/14/workflow-manager-disaster-recovery/

Answer (score 0):

Your topology is wrong, Workflow manager support either 1 or 3 or 5 server farm. But you have to 2 server farm.

for multi server farm, you need a load balancer , DNS and Certificate to build it. here is guide: http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm2.aspx

**You have to test it first before going to prod.** I  would follow try these steps.

- Perform the full backup of the WFM databases
- Remove the bad server from WFM farm, by running the WFM config wizard. (please note, i am talking WFM wizard not SharePoint PSconfig wizard)
- Now re-register the worklfow manager scope with SharePoint, before it will using the bad server url (https://badserver:12290/sharepoint),Now it will be newserver url.
- Run Copy-SPActivitiesToWorkflowService
- test the workflows.

Or

- remove both server from WFM farm using wfm wizard
- Configure single server WFM on good server using the restore
  method(you mentioned in ur reply).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have 2 WFEs and no load balancer - We just want to be able to have everything working on 1 WFE in case the other is down through a manual failover. IS this possible? In my current scnerario the "bad server" is only shut down to test failover. I would want the workflows ot keep running whether WFE1 or WFE2 is down. How can this be achieved?

Comment: as I mentioned earlier for WFM, you need 1 or 3 or 5 server topology. You need a load balancer so that it automatically direct the wf traffic between servers. In you case, i think you need DR type solution rather High Available...if one WFM down then you have to manually fail over to second farm.

Comment: so i deleted both servers from the workflow farm, and recreated a new workflow farm on one server. workflows still not working - i created a new coz restore was giving me all sorts of errors - any sort of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to restore otherwise your scope will change...then you have to republish all workflows

Comment: please give me steps to restore

Comment: for example where od i get the EncryptionCertificateThumbprint  and FarmCertificateThumbprint from?

Comment: from the old server, where the WFM was running (i mean bad Server)....the blog you follow clearly mention that

Comment: ok well i am clearly missing something coz half of the command s in the blog fail for me. if u can tell me the correct steps after each other it would be helpful.

Comment: You have to, export the certificate from old server, import of new server, then follow the steps from the middle of the page of the blog ( fromt his location: Here are the new steps:)

Comment: well the certificate was already there, the commands keep failing for different reasons - i am starting from 0 if this is possible, is it?!

Comment: if you start from scracth then you have to republish your workflows (all sharepoint 2013 only)

Comment: ok so back to square one. I now have 2 WFEs, WFManager installed on 1 WFE with all workflows re-published. What will happen with this WFE is down, will workflows keep working?